# Using debug versions of YUI2 components in YUI3

Tags: javascript, debugging, yui, script-debugging

I am using YUI 2 components in YUI3 using the standard way YAHOO has provided to get accesss to the YAHOO namespace.

However when YUI3 loads the yui2 components it loads teh min version which is no good for debugging.  I'm having problems with the editor rendering and was hoping to try to use the code to debug.

Is there a way I can force the YUI3 library to load full/debug versions of YUI2 components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that simply doing tab-view-debug doesn't work.  I guess it cant be done in this way.